# Some conditions on $\tilde f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle g(x,y) & \text{if }(x,y)\not=(0,0), \\ 0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

The following function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y)\not=(0,0), \\ 0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
is differentiable in the origin and admits tangent plane $z=0$. Perhaps my question is too general and I apologize for this. By translation of the variables, $x-x_0, y-y_0$ it is possible build another function that has the same property of previous function (e.g. tangent plane $z=0$) in the point $(x_0, y_0)$. But I'm looking for another change of variables $x$ and $y$, in which the "new" function, which we will denote as $\tilde f (x,y)$, is such that
$$\tilde f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle g(x,y) & \text{if }(x,y)\not=(0,0), \\ 0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
where $g(x,y)$ is not defined in $(0,0)$ (as $\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}$) and the tangent plane at origin isn't the trivial plane $z=c$ (c constant).

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the transformation to be differentiable, then the Jacobian of $\bar{f}$ will be the Jacobian of the transformation multiplied by the Jacobian of $f$ (which is the zero row matrix). So you will get zero again, and thus what you want is not possible, at least for 'reasonable' transformations.

$$\pmatrix{\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial y}}=J\pmatrix{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}=J\pmatrix{0&0}=\pmatrix{0&0}$$